# loop to create files from data frame

Tags: r, loops, split, save

I am basically new in R. I have a data frame presented below and I would like to create multiple files from the original data frame maintaining the first two columns while using the rest of the data frame as my third column. Each of the new data frame will be save as new file.
here's the scenario:

Original data frame

```
data                                                      
   id x1 x2 x3
 1  A  1 11 4
 2  A  2 12 6
 3  B  3 13 7
 4  B  4 14 9
 5  B  5 15 8
 6  C  6 16 10
```

What I  would like to create

```
data1
   id x1 x2
 1  A  1 11
 2  A  2 12
 3  B  3 13
 4  B  4 14
 5  B  5 15
 6  C  6 16

data2
   id x1  x3
 1  A  1  4
 2  A  2  6
 3  B  3  7
 4  B  4  9
 5  B  5  8
 6  C  6  10
```

Comment: What is the main question? File creation or 'splitting' the original dataframe? Furthermore I do not understand why you would like to use a loop here.

Comment: The main issue is to split the dataframe ( it has 390 columns), but I would like to maintained the first two column in every file whereas the third column will be replaced by the remaining columns in the data frame (hence 3:388 columns). at the end of the command, I should have 388 data frames with the same col 1 and col 2. I am thinking of looping since it will get the columns in the data frame.

Comment: Ok. I see. I misunderstood it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
mylist <- list()
for(i in  seq_along(df[,3:ncol(df)])){
  mylist[[i]] <- df[,c(1,2,(i+2))]
}
```

And to extract each df,

```
names(mylist) = paste0('data',3:(length(mylist)+2))
list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing this. I also needed to save each data frame and each should be named based on the 3rd column name. Any idea how should I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see the edit above and note that you can change the names as you wish!

Comment: I think you cannot pass a dataframe to seq_along. Btw. why don't you use a simple seq call instead of it: seq(3, ncol(df)); then you can subset the data by df[, c(1,2, i)]. Probably it is easier to read as a code.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my first problem. 
I've already extracted the dataframe, now I need to run a a function loop using the data. 
Each dataframe should be use as input to the linear mixed model and the result (varComp) should be stored in another dataframe bearing the name of the trait.